# After updating, getting "Could not resolve the subpath" error

Tags: assets, matrix, error-message, updating

After updating to 2.6.2973, saving any entry fails, resulting in an Internal Server Error: "Could not resolve the subpath '{slug}'".

I've read the similar errors on here which trace back to Matrix Asset objects and dynamically-named folders, though I'm not using any dynamically-named folders, and I can't tell where it's pulling {slug} from, and/or what's causes the issue. I've gone through and double-checked and resaved both asset directory and field configurations.

The log again points in the direction of the Matrix Asset, and refers to the folder id "1" -- a Local Source which has both the System Path and URL completely hardcoded. The top of the trace looks like so:

```
#0 /[directory-path]/craft/app/fieldtypes/AssetsFieldType.php(707): Craft\AssetsFieldType->_resolveSourcePathToFolderId('1', '{slug}', true)
#1 /[directory-path]/craft/app/fieldtypes/AssetsFieldType.php(327): Craft\AssetsFieldType->_determineUploadFolderId(Object(Craft\Model))
#2 /[directory-path]/craft/app/services/ElementsService.php(1618): Craft\AssetsFieldType->onAfterElementSave()
#3 /[directory-path]/craft/app/services/MatrixService.php(778): Craft\ElementsService->saveElement(Object(Craft\MatrixBlockModel), false)
#4 /[directory-path]/craft/app/services/MatrixService.php(882): Craft\MatrixService->saveBlock(Object(Craft\MatrixBlockModel), false)
#5 /[directory-path]/craft/app/fieldtypes/MatrixFieldType.php(533): Craft\MatrixService->saveField(Object(Craft\MatrixFieldType))
```

This error stalls all the client's content entry, so I hoping for any additional insights or tips. Thanks so much.

Comment: The stack trace indicates you've got an Assets field inside of a Matrix field with an upload folder location set to `{slug}`. Are you sure you're looking at the correct Matrix field/Asset field combination?

Comment: That was it, Brad -- I hadn't realized I set a {slug} subfolder within the Matrix/Asset field, which needed to be {owner.slug}. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help!  Will go ahead and add it as an official answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're setting an dynamic upload folder location for an Assets field inside of a Matrix field, you need to preface things like `{slug}` with `{owner.slug}`.

See the note about dynamic subfolders on an Assets field inside of Matrix here: https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths

Comment: Glad this question was on here. Just had the same issue, where dynamic subfolders were working for standard fields, but not Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I found issue using {slug} in Global when sharing same asset field. Ended up leaving {slug} in entries field and using {id} for Global asset field (created new field), not sure if there is a better way to use Asset in global